# Update all attributes of a node in XQUERY

Tags: xml, database, xquery, xquery-update

I have a node with attributes and children.

```
<node attr1="value1" attr2="value2"><child1/><child2/></node>
```

I have a second node with a different set of attributes:

```
<node attr1="value1_new" attr3="value3_new"/>
```

I want to replace all attributes of the first node with the attributes from the second, preserving children. Missing attributes from the second node should be deleted.
The desired result is:

```
<node attr1="value1_new" attr3="value3_new"><child1/><child2/></node>
```

This command will replace all contents of the node, thus removing children:

```
let $replacement = <node attr1="value1_new" attr3="value3_new"/>
replace node /node[1] with $replacement
```

How to update attributes and keep children?

Comment: While asking an XQuery question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XQuery that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output based on the #1 above.
(4) XQuery processor and its conformance with the XQuery standards: 1.0, 3.0, 3.1, or 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

With the various XQuery update extensions that BaseX supports the following works for me with BaseX 10.4

```
copy $n1 := <node attr1="value1" attr2="value2"><child1/><child2/></node>,
     $n2 := <node attr1="value1_new" attr3="value3_new"/>
modify ( 
 delete node $n1/@*,
 insert node $n2/@* into $n1
)
return $n1
```

to return the result

```
<node attr1="value1_new" attr3="value3_new"><child1/><child2/></node>
```